# How to set up Android build on Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, gradlew

I am fairly new to VSTS and the whole Microsoft Online Services Platform.

I am facing a problem when trying to initialise a build on our VSTS repository. I have selected the default Android build setting from the drop down menu, but it does not work. Every time I try to build, I reach the `gradlew build` stage and I get the error: `Error: D:\a\1\s\gradlew.bat failed with return code: 1`

I can build the code using the android Studio IDE, but I now need to use VSTS.
`
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: Here is the full log of the build

```
2018-07-28T19:23:31.6824618Z ##[section]Starting: gradlew build
2018-07-28T19:23:31.6830050Z ==============================================================================
2018-07-28T19:23:31.6830213Z Task         : Gradle
2018-07-28T19:23:31.6830359Z Description  : Build using a Gradle wrapper script
2018-07-28T19:23:31.6830487Z Version      : 2.137.1
2018-07-28T19:23:31.6830608Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-07-28T19:23:31.6830766Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613720)
2018-07-28T19:23:31.6830930Z ==============================================================================
2018-07-28T19:23:33.2899535Z SonarQube analysis is enabled.
2018-07-28T19:23:33.2900156Z Checkstyle analysis is enabled.
2018-07-28T19:23:33.2900406Z FindBugs analysis is enabled.
2018-07-28T19:23:33.2900654Z PMD analysis is enabled.
2018-07-28T19:23:33.2900905Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2018-07-28T19:23:33.2901941Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "D:\a\1\s\gradlew.bat build sonarqube -I D:\a\_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\2.137.1\node_modules\codeanalysis-common\checkstyle.gradle -I D:\a\_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\2.137.1\node_modules\codeanalysis-common\findbugs.gradle -I D:\a\_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\2.137.1\node_modules\codeanalysis-common\pmd.gradle"
2018-07-28T19:24:05.3436260Z Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
2018-07-28T19:24:29.2233239Z Unzipping C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.6-all\bcst21l2brirad8k2ben1letg\gradle-4.6-all.zip to C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.6-all\bcst21l2brirad8k2ben1letg
2018-07-28T19:25:41.8632779Z Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
```

{A series of downloads for the packages we use, omitted for character limit's sake}

```
2018-07-28T19:26:20.6092629Z Applying the Checkstyle plugin to project s
2018-07-28T19:26:20.6792218Z Applying the FindBugs plugin to project s
2018-07-28T19:26:20.6792841Z Applying the PMD plugin to all projects
2018-07-28T19:26:23.9485033Z Applying the Checkstyle plugin to project volve
2018-07-28T19:26:23.9621010Z Applying the FindBugs plugin to project volve
2018-07-28T19:26:23.9621425Z Applying the PMD plugin to all projects
2018-07-28T19:26:28.6406403Z support library package not found: android.support.constraint.
2018-07-28T19:26:28.6407012Z support library package not found: android.support.constraint.motion.
2018-07-28T19:26:28.6407656Z support library package not found: android.support.constraint.
2018-07-28T19:26:28.6407994Z support library package not found: android.support.constraint.
2018-07-28T19:26:28.6408285Z support library package not found: android.support.constraint.
2018-07-28T19:26:28.6408525Z support library package not found: android.support.constraint.
2018-07-28T19:26:28.6408784Z support library package not found: android.support.constraint.
2018-07-28T19:26:28.6409785Z support library package not found: android.support.constraint.
2018-07-28T19:26:28.6410031Z support library package not found: android.support.constraint.
2018-07-28T19:26:28.6410325Z support library package not found: android.support.constraint.
2018-07-28T19:26:28.6410567Z support library package not found: android.support.constraint.
2018-07-28T19:26:28.6410830Z support library package not found: android.support.constraint.
2018-07-28T19:26:39.5509667Z Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
2018-07-28T19:26:39.6403284Z registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
2018-07-28T19:26:39.7610924Z registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
2018-07-28T19:26:39.7830309Z Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
2018-07-28T19:26:39.7922748Z registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
2018-07-28T19:26:39.8933520Z registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
2018-07-28T19:26:39.9253837Z 
2018-07-28T19:26:39.9254479Z FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2018-07-28T19:26:39.9254716Z 
2018-07-28T19:26:39.9254905Z * What went wrong:
2018-07-28T19:26:39.9255123Z Task 'sonarqube' not found in root project 's'.
2018-07-28T19:26:39.9255269Z 
2018-07-28T19:26:39.9255429Z * Try:
2018-07-28T19:26:39.9255675Z Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
2018-07-28T19:26:39.9255897Z 
2018-07-28T19:26:39.9256078Z * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
2018-07-28T19:26:39.9256222Z 
2018-07-28T19:26:39.9256413Z BUILD FAILED in 2m 49s
2018-07-28T19:26:40.5195018Z Error: D:\a\1\s\gradlew.bat failed with return code: 1
2018-07-28T19:26:40.5195970Z     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\a\_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\2.137.1\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\toolrunner.js:569:30)
2018-07-28T19:26:40.5196934Z     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
2018-07-28T19:26:40.5197445Z     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
2018-07-28T19:26:40.5198292Z     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
2018-07-28T19:26:40.5198771Z     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
2018-07-28T19:26:40.6483964Z ##[warning]No test result files matching D:\a\1\s\**\TEST-*.xml were found, so publishing JUnit test results is being skipped.
2018-07-28T19:26:40.6494902Z ##[error]Error: D:\a\1\s\gradlew.bat failed with return code: 1
2018-07-28T19:26:40.6541754Z ##[section]Finishing: gradlew build
```

Comment: Can you share the full or a more detailed log of the build?

Comment: @MicheleFerracin I've put up the error log from that particular stage of the build.

Comment: Same error? Any solution? In my case, the project has multiple modules.

Comment: None as of yet @eC Droid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Android build template** to build your android project in VSTS.

[image]

Detail configuration for **Gradle task** as below:

- Gradle wrapper: relative path to `gradlew` file
- Working directory: same directory where `gradlew` file exist. It use `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` directory by default.
- Tasks: build

Such as if the android project with the file structure as [intro_android_demo](https://github.com/codepath/intro_android_demo) (`gradlew` file in the root directory of the repo), then the Gradle task configuration should as below:

[image]

Comment: I have tried this, but it still doesn't seem to work out, although I am now getting a "partially succeeded" build